# How to change delimiters (",", ".", "|" ) in csv file to comma (",")

Tags: php, string, file, csv, replace

Having a Japanese formatted CSV file with multiple delimiters like japanese comma, dot, japanese AND mark. 
thats is shows in bold letter(・､.) below. I have to change as comma.

> 009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,**防水・ﾁｪｯｸ**,,,,,ＷＥＢ
>   009M051,103,基礎工事（分離）,@E15142,㈱晃和建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,**13､14-1**,,,,,ＷＥＢ
>   009M051,344,外構工事,@E21502,桜井ジューキ㈱,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,**A.B**,,,,,ＷＥＢ

Need the output like

> 009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,防水,ﾁｪｯｸ,,,,,ＷＥＢ
>   009M051,103,基礎工事（分離）,@E15142,㈱晃和建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,13,14-1,,,,,ＷＥＢ
>   009M051,344,外構工事,@E21502,桜井ジューキ㈱,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,A,B,,,,,ＷＥＢ

give me some idea to change using PHP or VBA. thanks in advance...

Comment: `preg_replace('[・､.]',',',$text)` in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your csv is named 1.csv and have the following inside:

009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,防水・ﾁｪｯｸ,,,,,ＷＥＢ 009M051,103,基礎工事（分離）,@E15142,㈱晃和建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,13､14-1,,,,,ＷＥＢ 009M051,344,外構工事,@E21502,桜井ジューキ㈱,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,A.B,,,,,ＷＥＢ

You can do this:

```
<?php

$file = '1.csv';

$strings = file_get_contents($file);

$search = array('・', '､', '.');
$strings = str_replace($search, ',', $strings);

file_put_contents($file, $strings);

?>
```

Comment: $str = "009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,●、防水．ﾁｪｯｸ,,,,,ＷＥＢ"                                    could not find Japanese comma , AND mark (、．)

Comment: this is my file contents.....                                                                 009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,●、防水．ﾁｪｯｸ,,,,,ＷＥＢ
009M051,103,基礎工事（分離）,@E15142,㈱晃和建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,13､14-1,,,,,ＷＥＢ
009M051,344,外構工事,@E21502,桜井ジューキ㈱,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,A.B,,,,,ＷＥＢ

Comment: I use the string that you have in your question and it worked, see my edit

Comment: declared as string its working... but read from csv file not working... may be a encoding problem???

Comment: $strings = "009M051,105,造作工事（分離）,@E53405,藤本建設,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1､防水・ﾁｪｯｸ,,,,,ＷＥＢ";
$search = array('・', '､', '.');
$strings = str_replace($search, ',', $strings);
echo $strings;   its working great... but read from csv file, not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

iconv : http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

character set : http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

if you are using **fputcsv** Try to pass all parameters for better accuracy

```
int fputcsv ( $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: If you read CSV correctly then there is no need to use str_replace() which is very time consuming while processing large amount of data...